# What is affected by PIP Upgrade?

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

i want to install flake8-pep3101. but the system says that it needs to upgrade pip to 19.1.1 (currently it is 19.0.3). What will be affected by this upgrade ? I already have pep257, mypy and flake8 installed. Do they get affected by this upgrade. Eg : they will be not working ?

Comment: `pip` has nothing to do with packages themselves, it only retrieves them and installs them. So no, nothing will be affected and you should upgrade `pip`

Comment: all right. this give me some confidance

Answer (score 3):

pip is a package manager, upgrading it will not have any effect on your pre-existing packages.

That being said, they always improve the way that the package manager works and its recommended to keep it up to date (especially for heavy users)

Read more [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 1):

> but the system says that it needs to upgrade pip to 19.1.1

You may or you may not to do that since you are already in 19.0.3.
Check the [release notes](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/), if you need more info on what happened.

BTW, I found the release notes on [this page](https://github.com/pypa/pip).